# Jena- Storing date in xml dateTime- Unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, rdf, jena, ontology

I am using `…,model.createTypedLiteral(cal))` to store the value of xml dateTime dataTypeProperty.

The issue is, the time is not saved in my local time zone (UTC+05:00) Islamabad, Karachi) PKT. When I `System.get.out.println(cal)`, it shows me time in local time zone. But when I do   this `…,model.createTypedLiteral(cal))` and write it on owl file, the hour portion is saved with 5 hours subtracted (-05:00). here is my code:

```
...
1)Date date = new Date();
2)Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
3)cal.setTime(date);

4)System.out.println(cal);
...
5)Resource resource = model.createResource(resourceURI);
6)resource.addProperty(model.createProperty(baseURI+propertyName), model.createTypedLiteral(cal));
...
write model on owl file
...
```

Line 4 prints

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1406441262261,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Karachi",offset=18000000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=12,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=6,WEEK_OF_YEAR=31,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=27,DAY_OF_YEAR=208,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=0,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=11,MINUTE=7,SECOND=42,MILLISECOND=261,ZONE_OFFSET=18000000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

See `HOUR=11, HOUR_OF_DAY=11` its correct local time.

But line 6 and line 6 onward writes the same to owl file, where it saves in owl as

```
<created rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"
>2014-07-27T06:07:42.261Z</created>
```

which is -5:00 of my local time.

I have write code to retrieve it back from owl file and print on screen

```
    1)List<String> dlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    2)dlist= ...;
    3)System.out.println(dlist.get(0));

     String s = dlist.get(0);
     SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
     try {
        Date date1 = sd.parse(s);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date1);
    4)  System.out.println(cal);
    5)  System.out.println(cal.getTime()+" "+cal.getTimeZone());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

output of:

Line 3

```
2014-07-27T06:07:42.261Z^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime
```

Line 4

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1406423262000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Karachi",offset=18000000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=12,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=6,WEEK_OF_YEAR=31,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=27,DAY_OF_YEAR=208,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=0,HOUR=6,HOUR_OF_DAY=6,MINUTE=7,SECOND=42,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=18000000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

Line 5

```
Sun Jul 27 06:07:42 PKT 2014 sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Karachi",offset=18000000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=12,lastRule=null]
```

All outputs shows time in -5:00

Please guide me where is the issue?

=====================

PS

If above example is complicated then here is simple one:

```
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    Resource resource = model.createResource("http://example.com/resource/test");
    Property property = model.createProperty("http://example.com/prop/test");
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current time is. cal="+cal.getTime());
    Literal value = model.createTypedLiteral(cal);
    System.out.println("Current time saved in value as= "+value);
    String s1 = value.toString();
    SimpleDateFormat sd1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    Date date3;
    try {
        date3 = sd1.parse(s1);
        cal.setTime(date3);
        System.out.println("Retrieving back the time from value variable as date="+cal.getTime());
    resource.addProperty(property, value);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output:

```
Current time is. cal=Sun Jul 27 13:04:53 PKT 2014
Current time saved in value as= 2014-07-27T08:04:53.681Z^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime
Retrieving back the time from value variable as date=Sun Jul 27 08:04:53 PKT 2014
```

In results, time shown in first line is different from second line. Why is this so?

Comment: **it shows me time in local time zone. But when I … write it on owl file, the hour portion is saved with 5 hours subtracted (-05:00).** The output you showed was **2014-07-27T06:07:42.261Z**.  The **Z** at the end mean it's saving the date time normalized to GMT. It's the **same** time, just written in for a different time zone.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor is it possible to write xml:DateTime in local time on owl file?

Comment: Well, it's the same time, so I don't know whether RDF libraries will tend to normalize or not (and it doesn't really matter, since you're still talking about the same time, after all), but you could construct a typed literal manually with the lexical form and the datatype.  I *think* that an implementation could still normalize, just like "1"^^xsd:boolean and "true"^^xsd:boolean represent the same value.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code in

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.util.NodeFactoryExtra.dateTimeToNode
```

or the routine it uses:

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.util.Utils.calendarToXSDDateTimeString(...)
```

to get the lexical form then create a typed literal of type xsd;dateTime.

These compensates for the fact that Xerces normalizes to timezone Z.